# OpenCL: buffering inputs for the same kernel

Tags: buffer, opencl

I have been trying to read a file and load it into a buffer of a kernel in OpenCL, while the kernel is processing another buffer. However, it seems to not like that: for some reason, the results are wrong.

First, I tried setting the Args for the same kernel every time before enqueueing a task. Then, I tried enqueuing tasks for 2 kernels of the same function like below, without changing the arguments:

```cpp
krnl_1.setArg(0, buffer_a));
krnl_1.setArg(1, output_buffer));
krnl_2.setArg(0, buffer_b));
krnl_2.setArg(1, output_buffer));

void* ptr[2];
ptr[0] = q.enqueueMapBuffer(buffer_a, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ | CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, buffer_size_in_bytes, NULL, NULL, &err);
ptr[1] = q.enqueueMapBuffer(buffer_b, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ | CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, buffer_size_in_bytes, NULL, NULL, &err);

int sel = 0;
long long bytes_sent = 0;

// Fill buffer_a
bytes_sent += pread(myFd, (void*)ptr[sel], buffer_size_in_bytes, bytes_sent);
    
while (bytes_sent < total_size_in_bytes){ 
    
    if (sel == 0){ // If buffer_a was just filled
        q.enqueueTask(krnl_1);
        sel = 1; // Fill buffer_b
    } else {  // If buffer_b was just filled
        q.enqueueTask(krnl_2);
        sel = 0; // Fill buffer_a
    }
    
    if (bytes_sent >= total_size_in_bytes) // If this is the last task
        q.enqueueMigrateMemObjects({output_buffer},CL_MIGRATE_MEM_OBJECT_HOST);
    else // Fill the buffer that is not being processed
        bytes_sent += pread(myFd, (void*)ptr[sel], buffer_size_in_bytes, bytes_sent);

    q.finish();
    
}
```

If I do it serially, it is working fine:

```cpp
void* ptr[2];
ptr[0] = q.enqueueMapBuffer(buffer_a, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ | CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, buffer_size_in_bytes, NULL, NULL, &err);
ptr[1] = q.enqueueMapBuffer(buffer_b, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ | CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, buffer_size_in_bytes, NULL, NULL, &err);

int sel = 0;
long long bytes_sent = 0;
    
while (bytes_sent < total_size_in_bytes){ 

    bytes_sent += pread(myFd, (void*)ptr[sel], buffer_size_in_bytes, bytes_sent);
    
    if (sel == 0){
        q.enqueueTask(krnl_1);
        sel = 1;
    } else {  
        q.enqueueTask(krnl_2);
        sel = 0;
    }
    
    if (bytes_sent >= total_size_in_bytes) //if this is the last task
        q.enqueueMigrateMemObjects({output_buffer},CL_MIGRATE_MEM_OBJECT_HOST);

    q.finish();
    
}
```

I feel like I must have miscomprehended the way OpenCL treats arguments and enqueues tasks, but I cannot find any similar examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, reads and writes by a kernel executing on a device to a memory region mapped for writing are undefined (for more information please see [Accessing mapped regions of a memory object](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenCL/sdk/2.1/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueMapBuffer.html) section for `clEnqueueMapBuffer`). Therefore, it is necessary to unmap the buffer before run the task.

Second, `bytes_sent` is incremented before it is checked in `while()` condition in the first example. If the first call of `pread()` reads all data, the loop won't be executed.

Therefore, I expect that the code should look something like this:

```cpp
krnl_1.setArg(0, buffer_a);
krnl_1.setArg(1, output_buffer);
krnl_2.setArg(0, buffer_b);
krnl_2.setArg(1, output_buffer);

int sel = 0;
long long bytes_processed = 0;

void* buf_ptr = q.enqueueMapBuffer(buffer_a, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, buffer_size_in_bytes, NULL, NULL, &err);
long long bytes_to_process = pread(myFd, buf_ptr, buffer_size_in_bytes, bytes_processed);
err = q.enqueueUnmapMemObject(buffer_a, buf_ptr);

while (bytes_processed < total_size_in_bytes)
{
    if (sel == 0){ // If buffer_a was just filled
        q.enqueueTask(krnl_1);
        sel = 1; // Fill buffer_b
    } else {  // If buffer_b was just filled
        q.enqueueTask(krnl_2);
        sel = 0; // Fill buffer_a
    }

    bytes_processed += bytes_to_process;

    if (bytes_processed < total_size_in_bytes) { // Fill the buffer that is not being processed
        auto& buffer = sel ? buffer_b : buffer_a;
        buf_ptr = q.enqueueMapBuffer(buffer, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, buffer_size_in_bytes, NULL, NULL, &err);
        bytes_to_process = pread(myFd, buf_ptr, buffer_size_in_bytes, bytes_processed);
        err = q.enqueueUnmapMemObject(buffer, buf_ptr);
    }
    else { // If this is the last task
        buf_ptr = q.enqueueMapBuffer(output_buffer, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, 0, output_buffer_size_in_bytes, NULL, NULL, &err);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that and get back! The while condition is not a problem because in my application, total_size_in_bytes >> buffer_size_in_bytes.